# Why timer generates a new session?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I've faced with a strange problem.

I have an event in GTM that triggered by Timer every 5 sec.

[image] [image]

GA pageview tag (gtag) is implemented hardcoded above GTM.

In reports I see a lot of sessions with landing page `(not set)`. It seems that timer generates a new session every time.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure the GTM GA tag (which creates named tracker instances) and gtag.js (which does not create ga tracker objects at all) can really be mixed in the same page. You could try to use a custom HTML tag with gtag event tracking instead of using the tag template to see if this helps with your problem.

Comment: @EikePierstorff Google Support says it's ok: "Tag Manager and gtag.js are built on the same infrastructure, and should work properly if deployed on the same page." https://developers.google.com/gtagjs/#google_tag_manager_or_gtagjs But thanks, I'll try.

Comment: That they both work does not mean they will actually write to the same Google Analytics session - if the problems started after you started mixing the two then it might be worth looking into this (after all it says "GTM and gtag", not "GA via GTM and gtag", so I don't feel that the documentation is really clear on this point).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should first remove the GTM code on the page and see if the landing pages are showing up fine to find out if mixing both is causing the issue

Comment: I can't remove GTM, it's client's site with big traffic. I've already migrated `gtag` inside GTM. But problem is not solved: for part of sessions Timer event generates a new session. I had to delete the Timer event. I didn't find the reason.

Comment: after you removed the timer , is landing page working fine and not showing as "not set " ?

Comment: A few users continued their strange sessions, gradually for 3 days everything became normal.